# C++ Convert LARGE_INTEGER to String

Tags: c++, winapi, tostring

I've got this larger integer which is formed by an operation

```
__int64 c = (bytesTransferred.HighPart*2^31 + bytesTransferred.LowPart) * 100/(fileSize.HighPart*2^31 + bytesTransferred.LowPart);
```

How can I convert it to string to show it in a messagebox for example? I tried:

```
std::string percent;
std::stringstream strstream;
strstream << c;
strstream >> percent;
```

But didn't work.

Comment: `operator^()` is bitwise XOR (see [Arithmetic operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe :

```
 std::stringstream strstream;
 strstream << c;
 std::string percent(strstream.str());
```

Or try a look at _i64toa() function.

Answer (score 6):

`std::string to_string( long long value );`

defined in `<string>`
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string

Answer (score 2):

First of all your calculation seems wrong: I guess the rightmost part of it was intended to be `fileSize.LowPart` instead of `bytesTransferred.LowPart`.
A better way to do the calculation of `c` could be

```
#include <cstdint>
int64_t c = (bytesTransferred.QuadPart * 100) / fileSize.QuadPart;
```

Then for conversion to string you could do:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << c;
std::string percent = ss.str();
```

Comment: `bytesTransferred.QuadPart * 100` potentially overflows the valid range of `__int64`.

Comment: @IInspectable,  that happens only if file size is at least 8 388 608 TB (Terabytes).

Comment: That is correct, thanks for the confirmation. One possible solution is `__int64 c = (bytesTransferred.QuadPart * 100.0) / fileSize.QuadPart + 0.5;`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with your string conversion, there is a problem with your LARGE_INTEGER math. Try this:

```
__int64 c = (bytesTransferred.QuadPart * 100) / (fileSize.QuadPart)
```

Comment: `bytesTransferred.QuadPart * 100` potentially overflows the valid range of `__int64`.